# When trying to install windows 7 I got an error of "operating system not found" how could I fix it?

Tags: windows-7

This is the complete error I get when I try to boot from DVD

```
For Atheros PCIE Ethernet controller v1.0.0.5(01/22/09)
Check cable connection!
PXE-M0F: Existing Intel PXE ROM.
Operating system no found
```

What could be the problem. Could it by my windows 7 disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default your PC might be set for booting only from HDD and Network.

```
   PXE-M0F: Existing Intel PXE ROM.
```

The former message tells you the Network boot failed.

Just enable booting from DVD at bios level and you'll be fine.